# Passing parameters to jQuery function via link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery function:

```
$(function(){ 
function InitDialog(c,b){
    /* some code */     
}

$('a[name=dialog]').click(function(e)                                                 {         
            InitDialog(caption, bodyText);        
    fadeInCommon(e,this);
});
});
```

And also I have a link defined in html code like below:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#dialog" name="someInformation" }">something</a></li>
</ul>
```

My question is how can I pass the parameters (caption, bodyText) to Init() function via link?
I've heard about some method like below:

```
<li><a href="#dialog" name="someInformation" onClick="return {height: 100, width:200};"}">something</a></li>
```

But I don't understand how can I get and parse it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first, I think you want to say `$('a[href="#dialog"]')` to get the a tags, then in the click function, `$(this).attr("name")` will give you the some information, which you could store a json string...

```
<a href="#dialog" name="{caption:'XXXX', bodyText:'XXXX'}">My Text</a>

$('a[href="#dialog"]').click(function() {
     var data = JSON.parse($(this).attr("name"));
     InitDialog(data.caption, data.bodyText);
});
```

But, I don't think that's the right way of going about what you're trying to do, would you be better to create the dialog in a div lower down the page, hide it, and only show it when you click the link? Because the term 'bodyText' implies it's going to be big...

Or just:

```
 <a href="javascript:InitDialog('Caption', 'BodyText'); fadeInCommon(e,this);">My Link</a>
```

Comment: name="{'caption':'XXXX', 'bodyText':'XXXX'}" - you forgot quotes! Then I should use replaceAll function to replace ' to " After that it will work!

Comment: Oh sorry I did too, I was thinking about it like a JS object and not a JSON string. Single quotes should work though? That or say name="{\"caption\":\"....

Answer (score 7):

Since you are using jquery, I would recommend that you do the following to store data on your element

```
<a href="#dialog" name="some_name" data-params="{'param1':'someValue', 'param2':'someOtherValue'}">Link Text</a>
```

Then in your click function, you can access it as shown below

```
$('a#dialog').click(function(){
    var me = $(this), data = me.data('params');
    //console.log(data);
});
```

### Edit - Fiddle added

[Check the fiddle to see a working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/yayh3/3/)

Comment: Fiddle link is working fine

Answer (score 2):

using data-* attribute, you can:

```
<a name='dialog'
 data-caption='this is the caption'
 data-bodytext='this is the body'>klik</a>
```

and the javascript:

```
$(function() {
    function InitDialog(c, b){
        alert('the caption: ' + c);
        alert('the body: ' + b);
        }

    $('a[name=dialog]').click(function(e) {
        caption = $(this).data('caption'); // gets data-caption attribute value
        bodyText = $(this).data('bodytext'); // gets the data-bodytext attribute value
        InitDialog(caption, bodyText);
        fadeInCommon(e,this);
        });
    });
```

tho instead of using `name` as the selector, i'd recommend `class` instead